# Why bootstrap doesn't work although I have loaded it, etc. (Django project)?

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm working on this Django project. The functionality works perfectly fine. When I started working on the front-end using Bootstrap3, I ran into some issues (more like confusions).

First, I installed django-bootstrap3 using command prompt like so:

```
pip install django-bootstrap3
```

The installation was successful. Bootstrap3 was downloaded into this location in my computer *c:\python34\lib\site-packages* Then, I included it as a third-party app in  **settings.py** in the list of *INSTALLED_APPS* in my main project directory like so:

```
 INSTALLED_APPS =(
--apps--
'bootstrap3',
)
```

Also in **settings.py**, I included jQuery like so:

```
BOOTSTRAP3 = {'include_jquery': True}
```

I modified my *base.html* to include the bootstrap elements. I have two apps, *users* and *mynotess* (sorry for bad naming)

**base.html**

**EDIT**: base.html is at the bottom of question.

For some reason, I loaded up *localhost:8000* and it was still in the normal ugly HTML form. I checked online, and I found some CDN links and thought maybe if I just used the CDN links, it would work.

I then included this in **base.html**, copied right from Bootstrap's website.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

(I included the links in the *head* section and the scripts in the *body* section of the HTML document).

It worked! **However**, when I **removed the bootstrap3 from my INSTALLED_APPS** and all the code that loads up bootstrap3 that was installed on my computer (such as *{% load bootstrap3 %}*, it didn't work. It went back to the ugly HTML format. Similarly, when I **removed the CDN links** and kept all the bootstrap3 code that loaded bootstrap installed on my computer, it went back to the ugly HTML format as well.

My question is:

- Is it supposed to be like this? According to a book that I'm currently following for this project, I don't even have to include the CDN links and scripts (the book doesn't mention them **at all**) and it ought to work.
- If it's not supposed to be like this, is there something wrong with my code that's causing this? Am I missing some step? Are my bootstrap3 files in the correct directory? (i just downloaded it using pip through command prompt and I didn't move it anywhere else)

The functionality of my Django website works just fine.
Any help, explanations, or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**:
**base.html** would have to be like this if I wanted the Bootstrap elements to show up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load bootstrap3 %}
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- encoding characters -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!-- some Microsoft Edge/IE stuff -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- viewport -> the user's visible area of a webpage, -> this sets it to normal zoom (scale 1) and width of device -->
        <title>My Notes</title
        {% bootstrap_css %}
        {% bootstrap_javascript %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Static top navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar"></button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'mynotess:index' %}">My Notes</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <li><a href="{% url 'mynotess:topics' %}">My Topics</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <li><a>{{user.username}}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li><a href = "{% url 'users:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url 'users:register' %}">Create Account</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                {% block header %}{% endblock header %}
            </div>
            <div>
                {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I removed just the CDN links, it wouldn't work. Similarly, if I removed just the template tags, it wouldn't work either.

**base.html** without template tags (doesn't work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- encoding characters -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!-- some Microsoft Edge/IE stuff -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- viewport -> the user's visible area of a webpage, -> this sets it to normal zoom (scale 1) and width of device -->
        <title>My Notes</title
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Static top navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar"></button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'mynotess:index' %}">My Notes</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <li><a href="{% url 'mynotess:topics' %}">My Topics</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <li><a>{{user.username}}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li><a href = "{% url 'users:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url 'users:register' %}">Create Account</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                {% block header %}{% endblock header %}
            </div>
            <div>
                {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**base.html** without the links for CDN (also doesn't work)

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- encoding characters -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!-- some Microsoft Edge/IE stuff -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- viewport -> the user's visible area of a webpage, -> this sets it to normal zoom (scale 1) and width of device -->
        <title>My Notes</title
        {% bootstrap_css %}
        {% bootstrap_javascript %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Static top navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar"></button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'mynotess:index' %}">My Notes</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <li><a href="{% url 'mynotess:topics' %}">My Topics</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <li><a>{{user.username}}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li><a href = "{% url 'users:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url 'users:register' %}">Create Account</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                {% block header %}{% endblock header %}
            </div>
            <div>
                {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the usual typo stuff (title tags etc.), you already defined to import bootstrap, but the jquery line doesn't get loaded until you actually stick the jquery into the parameter to utilise it. (I just realised this is quite old as the new one is already on Bootstrap 4).

You don't need to manually include any cdn links, your django bootstrap tags can handle that part of it for you unless you decide to change the links (in which case you'd write your change to the settings in the settings.py (assuming that's what you're using).

So...

Including the bootstrap CSS is this tag:

```
{% bootstrap_css %}
```

And for including the bootstrap javascript and jquery js files - instead of:

```
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
```

try using:

```
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery=True %}
```

or:

```
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery %}
```

if you have already defined jquery as True in your config

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and we both made the same typo: you forgot ">" in your closing title tag

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `{% boostrap_css %}` is not pulling down the CSS. That would cause the issue you have described. You may want to update the settings so they are pulling from a CDN that you know works or just hard code them into your base template.

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- encoding characters -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!-- some Microsoft Edge/IE stuff -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- viewport -> the user's visible area of a webpage, -> this sets it to normal zoom (scale 1) and width of device -->
    <title>My Notes</title
    {# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript %}
</head>

<body>    
{# Display a form #}
<form action="/url/to/submit/" method="post" class="form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form my_form_here %}
  {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
    </button>
  {% endbuttons %}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py

```
BOOTSTRAP3 = {
    'jquery_url': '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    'base_url': '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/'
}
```

Comment: that also doesn't seem to work. It still appears as the HTML format. I have to actually include the CDN links into base.html. it seems like the Bootstrap elements would only show up if **both** the cdn links **and** the code that loads the template tags, etc. are in base.html. Also, when I commented out that BOOTSTRAP3 dictionary in settings.py, it still worked (as long as both the template tags and CDN links are there). Is that dictionary optional or is that a sign that something is wrong?

Comment: It sounds like this could be a bug in the package. The dict in your settings is optional. Would you be able to provide the rendered HTML with and without the `{% bootstrap_css %} {% bootstrap_javascript %}`?

Comment: i edited my post to include the HTML without the template tags and with them

Comment: @SteveD. If you open up the view source in your browser on your template without the CDN tags does the `{% bootstrap_css %} {% bootstrap_javascript %}` get converted to the correct tags?

Comment: it changes to   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: I just tried the CSS url and its giving me an `AccessDenied` error. That's likely whats causing the problem. I also have no idea why its giving an error because I got this url `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css` from bootstraps home page and it works without issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131924/discussion-between-emett-speer-and-steve-d).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Django for beginners book. If so be careful to check the folders in which you have placed your html files. I have fallen into this trap myself with this book. It isn't always clear in which directory they are creating new files.
In my case, I only noticed this when my bootstrap wouldn't work on my /admin & change_password pages, but it was working fine for 'home'.

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the configurations in settings.py file?
Please see this link
https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html